# Different microphones for machine learning dataset

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm currently following along with the Tensorflow simple audio recognition tutorial found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/audio_recognition)and wanted to know if having audio recorded by different microphones in my dataset will negatively affect the outcome of my training. Should all audio be recorded by the same type of microphone?

Comment: if the same microphone will be used later when you use your model, then yes. otherwise, no. suppose you train the model on samsung phone data, but in practice the app will be used on HTC then it's suboptimal. on the other hand if you develop an add for Amazon Alexa, then it makes a sense to tune for the mics (types) on Alexa, assuming they all have the same hardware

Comment: Ideally, yes. I have worked with human utterances and the last thing you want is to end up identify "speaker-related" variation" only for this information to be just an artefact of the recording process. Aside the "same microphone", also check that you have the "same bitrate/compression", this can have strong quantification effects.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, unless steps are taken to compensate models will often generalize poorly to even trivial changes in the inputs, like a different microphone.

One approach to generalize better, often used in deep learning, is Data Augmentation. It works by generating new training data by modifying input samples. For generalizing across different microphones, the most relevant augmentations are: changing the volume, adding noise (synthetic) and changing frequency response. Other common audio augmentations are time shifting, time stretching and mixing with real noise sources.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If your model will be applied to sound coming from one specific microphone, training the model on only sounds recorded with that microphone makes sense. However, if your model needs to be more robust, and perform well on sound recorded with different microphones, then you should have such variations in your dataset accordingly. As jonnor mentioned in his answer, one way to make your model generalize better to various microphones/environments/situations is to apply data augmentation to your audio to make more samples. I've created a Python package called audiomentations that can help you apply various data augmentation techniques to sound data. Check it out at https://github.com/iver56/audiomentations